# Rewrite Rule to Modify Requested URL in the httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I have existing rewrite rules set up in the httpd.conf file.
One of them checks if the HTTP_HOST matches the pattern (.*).example.com case-insensitively [NC]. If the requested URL is '/', it is internally rewritten to another URL that is not being shown in the browser. I mean that the browser shows / only without other parameters, like storeId=xxxx from the example below.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/?$ anotherURL?storeId=xxxxx [L,PT]
```

All functional URLs on the site start with "/online" in the URI like this "https://local.example.com/online/shop/".
However, there are some links that do not include "/online" in the URL, and as a result, these links do not work, like this "https://local.example.com/sale/"

Now, I'm attempting to create an additional rewrite rule for the same URL mentioned earlier. The purpose is to rewrite the links that do not contain "/online" (or if "/online" was manually removed from a working URL) in order to internally rewrite them and make the URL function in the same way as the original rule described above.

I have tried many assumptions, but all of them breaks the website's content and don't give the desired output. I am expecting when hitting these links to work fine

1. https://local.example.com/shop/
2. https://local.example.com/online/sale/ (If I manually removed /online)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired outcome, you can add an additional rewrite rule that handles the URLs that do not include "/online" in them. Here's an example of how you can modify your existing rewrite rules to accomplish this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle URLs with "/online" in them
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/online [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /online/$1 [L]

# Handle the root URL ("/")
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ anotherURL?storeId=xxxxx [L,PT]
```

Make sure to restart your web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I have tried this before but it caused the site content to be damaged for all previously working URLs. And when removing /online from the URLs gives a 404 not found error, the same result as before applying the new rule. That's what is confusing me.